# Calling Firebase Cloud Function URL in angularjs $http returns Access Control Origin Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

So I've built a cloud function that does some linking with Plaid. Now I'm trying to call that function using AngularJS's `$http` method. While the code is getting executed on the cloud function, I'm getting the error below in my console instead of the success response.

My AngularJS $http call

```
var token = 'randomGeneratedCode';

$http({
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
   },
   url: '<hidden-url>?token='+token
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Then the error that I am receiving is:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load <hidden-url>?token=randomGeneratedCode. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed access.`

For my firebase cloud functions, here is my `index.js` file, just in case it helps.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/hho25045/
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it was a server side issue, not an angularJs issue. If you add a header to your resolution within `index.js` you will remove this error and everything fires like it should.

```
exports.plaidLinkAccount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.header("Access-COntrol-Allow-Origin", "*);

    // ...
})
```

Comment: Fix to minor typo - that should be     
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");